# How to create a pie chart using the chart module in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, charts

I'm trying to create a pie chart using the [chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module. I was able to create a pie chart that looks similar to the pie chart shown on https://developers.google.com/chart/ . But I am not getting any percentages.

**My Question**: What is needed to also show those percentages, or what might I be doing wrong)?

Note: I cannot do those interactive additions, but I can live without them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided, as defined in [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: With my (accepted) edit from earlier today, I believe that the previous comment (from Molot) now longer applies ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do so. Use the [google chart tools](https://drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) to achieve that. This module also integrates with the views module nicely.

Comment: Thanks for this, great module, however i have 1 problem with this, I implemented it with views and created content type with title, field A and field B. Lets say field A is equal to 1, B is equal to 3.

I created a view with format google chart tools, added field A and B, problem is that pie chart does not work as expected. When I use columns for example, everything is great, I get two columns per node with values for fields A and B. When i change it to pie though, It only shows field A for each node, ignoring field B and presenting A as 100%. Is there any way of changing that?